# How to resize a button depending on the text in JavaFX?

Tags: java, button, javafx, resize

This might be a trivial question, but I wasn't able to find a solution so far.
If you create a button with a longer word as text, lets say 'Überspringen'(the german word for Skip), JavaFx will automatically truncate the Text to 'Übersprin'+EllipsisString. 
`Button skipButton = new Button("\u00dcberspringen");`
[image]

Is there an easy solution to avoid the truncation? I just could hardcode a new size, but in Swing the button-size was adjusted automatically.

I already tried `setWrapText(true)` but that didn't work, I think because there is no whitespace.

### Edit

This Minimal, Reproducible Example shows my issue:

```
public class ButtonTest extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
       Scene scene = new Scene(getBottomPanel(),600,50);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }

    private AnchorPane getBottomPanel()
    {
       HBox infraBox = new HBox(5);
       infraBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       infraBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Input (manuell):"));
       infraBox.getChildren().add(new TextField());

       Button shortButton = new Button("OK");
       Button longButton = new Button("\u00dcberspringen");
       ButtonBar buttonBar = new ButtonBar();
       buttonBar.getButtons().addAll(shortButton, longButton);

       AnchorPane bottomPanel = new AnchorPane(infraBox, buttonBar);
       bottomPanel.setPadding(new Insets(5));
       AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(infraBox, 0.0);
       AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(buttonBar, 5.0);
       return bottomPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: should work automagically,  so there might be something not quite right in your setup (make sure you use an appropriate layout) or you hit a bug :) Whatever the reason, same procedure as always: [mcve] required.

Comment: @kleopatra Thx! How about this?

Comment: hmm .. worksforme (fx17-dev, didn't check earlier versions)

Comment: This works for me too, JavaFX 15.0.1.

Comment: javafx.runtime.version=8.0.261
javafx.runtime.build=b12

Comment: ahh .. yeah, I also see it in fx8 - looks like some issue that's fixed in the meantime (okay in fx11). You might consider upgrading to a more recent version (current is fx16, many bugs fixes are backported to fx11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, so I hope somebody of you does....

#### Solution:

Just replace the AnchorPane with a BorderPane like this

```
public class ButtonTest extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
       Scene scene = new Scene(getBottomPanel(), 600, 50);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }

    private BorderPane getBottomPanel()
    {
       HBox infraBox = new HBox(5);
       infraBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       infraBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Input (manuell):"));
       infraBox.getChildren().add(new TextField());

       Button shortButton = new Button("OK");
       Button longButton = new Button("\u00dcberspringen");
       ButtonBar buttonBar = new ButtonBar();
       buttonBar.getButtons().addAll(shortButton, longButton);
          /*using BorderPane instead of AnchorPane*/
       BorderPane bottomPanel = new BorderPane();
       bottomPanel.setPadding(new Insets(5));
       bottomPanel.setLeft(infraBox);
       bottomPanel.setCenter(buttonBar);
       return bottomPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, it's a version issue - there seems to be something wrong in anchorPane layout in fx8 (okay in fx11)

Comment: Ahhhh, well thank you!
Where did you find this?

Comment: have run your example with different versions :) Don't know (and don't care, it's wayyy outdated) why it breaks in fx8, though.

Answer (score 2):

Normally buttons get resized so the label of the button is fully visible:

> "For example, the computed size of a Button object is determined by the length of the text and the size of the font used for the label, plus the size of any image. Typically, the computed size is just big enough for the control and the label to be fully visible." (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm).

However when you store your button in a container (e.g. `VBox` or `HBox`) that has a maximum width and height, for example, the button will be squeezed into that container, i.e. the label gets truncated:

> "By default, buttons grow only to their preferred size. However, buttons shrink to where the label is shown as three dots (...) if the minimum width is not overridden.".

The article I linked describes your problem:

> "To prevent a button from becoming smaller than its preferred width, set its minimum width to its preferred width" in the section "Keeping Nodes at Their Preferred Size".

If you did not set the preferred size of your button manually the computed size is used for its preferred size automatically:

> "By default, UI controls compute default values for their preferred size that is based on the content of the control"

Your code sample does not produce the described problem (for me):

[image: screenshot of sample application]

(Sry I would like to comment on your post, but my reputation is too low)

Comment: But you changed something in the code? In my provided example is no title set... What else did you change?

Comment: I only added a title (stage.setTitle("Test");). This does not interfere with the actual root node.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solve your problem

simply use computed size ...
that means : 
`button.setPrefSize(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);`
this method as i know set the width to the button suitable for the text
Sorry for the bad English

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solved my problem, but thank you anyways.

Comment: Just checked on win and macosx and this solutiona actually works. Instead it should be `button.setPrefWidth(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);`